# wp e-commerce group product by category

Tags: categories, sort, plugin-wp-e-commerce, order

Sorry for my bad english.
I have WP 3.3.1 & wp-e-commerce.3.8.7.6.2. On the products page (which use wpsc-products_page.php template) I have list of products. I want to group this products by category. For example:

****Cat1
Product 1
Product 2

**** Cat2
Product 1
Product 2

**** Cat3
Product 1
Product 2

I try to use this method, but it`s does not work

```
add_filter('posts_join', create_function('$a', 'global $wpdb; return $a . " INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) ";'));
add_filter('posts_where', create_function('$a', 'global $wpdb; return $a . " AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = \'wpsc_product_category\'";'));
add_filter('posts_orderby', create_function('$a','global $wpdb; return "$wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id DESC";'));
query_posts('');
```

Thank you all in advance for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

You are very close. I had the same problem a while ago, and [blogged about it](http://snippets.webaware.com.au/snippets/sort-wp-e-commerce-products-by-category-and-product-title/). Your join is missing one more join table, wp_terms, which has the term you want to sort on.

Here is the code I used:

```
class OrderWpscProducts {

    // flag for when a shop products post query is being created
    private $isProductQuery = false;

    public function __construct() {
        // hooks for altering order of product pages
        add_filter('parse_query', array($this, 'filterProductQueryMark'), 20);
        add_filter('posts_join', array($this, 'filterProductQueryJoins'), 20);
        add_filter('posts_orderby', array($this, 'filterProductQueryOrderBy'), 20);
    }

    /**
    * detect a posts query that should return a list of shop products, 
    * and mark it for later filters
    * @param WP_Query $query
    * @return WP_Query
    */
    public function filterProductQueryMark($query) {
        $this->isProductQuery = false;

        if (!is_admin() && (wpsc_is_in_category() || !empty($query->query_vars['wpsc_wine_style']))) {
            $this->isProductQuery = true;
        }
    }

    /**
    * if the posts query is for a list of shop products, 
    * then add some tables to the join so that we can sort by category name
    * @param string $joins
    * @return string
    */
    public function filterProductQueryJoins($joins) {
        global $wpdb;

        if ($this->isProductQuery) {
            $joins .= "
 INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships wpsc_cat_rel ON wp_posts.ID = wpsc_cat_rel.object_id
 INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy wpsc_cat_tax ON wpsc_cat_tax.term_taxonomy_id = wpsc_cat_rel.term_taxonomy_id
   and wpsc_cat_tax.taxonomy = 'wpsc_product_category'
 INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms wpsc_cat ON wpsc_cat.term_id = wpsc_cat_tax.term_id
";
        }

        return $joins;
    }

    /**
    * if the posts query is for a list of shop products, then sort by category name and product title
    * @param string $orderby
    * @return string
    */
    public function filterProductQueryOrderBy($orderby) {
        if ($this->isProductQuery) {
            $orderby = 'wpsc_cat.name ASC, wp_posts.post_title ASC';
        }

        return $orderby;
    }
}

// create instance, will be kept alive by hooks
new OrderWpscProducts();
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you can find a solution : http://subharanjan.in/category-wise-products-display-in-wp-e-commerce/

I am not sure if this will solve your problem.

Thanks!

Comment: [An answer should be more than just a link to an external site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion). Please add a solution.